# Who was informing the Suliban Cabal in the Temporal Cold War?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In *Star Trek: Enterpris*e, there was a silhouetted figure that was informing Silik and the rest of the Cabal. I don't recall ever seeing who he was, or what he was trying to do. Who was he?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## He was future Archer.

This was not revealed in the show itself, but by producer Brannon Braga on Twitter in 2012, and again in 2015.

Here are the 2012 tweets:

[image: Brannon Braga, 8:59 a.m. 26th November 2012: “RT@JamieFriend12:Mr Braga...if the show had a 5th season would have revealed who future guy was?//Yes. Future Guy was Archer.” Brannon Braga, 9:13 a.m. 26th November 2012: “RT@thejimsmith:..were Future Guy’s motives purer than we thought?//Archer was trying to correct history. He was pure in his own mind.” Brannon Braga, 1:40 p.m. 26th November 2012: “For those wondering, Archer as Future Guy was always the idea. Trying to repair a corrupt future by influencing his innocent past self.” Brannon Braga, 5:38 p.m. 26th November 2012: “RT @tronprogram2: thought Future Guy was supposed to be a Romulan?//There was talk of a Romulan red herring. But it’s Archer.”]

Here is the 2015 tweet:

> Archer was Future Guy.  He was manipulating his own destiny from the future.

([Source](https://mobile.twitter.com/BrannonBraga/status/597587988743213056))

According to the 2012 tweets, had the series secured a Season 5, the Archer = Future Guy reveal would have happened then.  Braga also says that future Archer's actions were an attempt "to correct history" and "repair a corrupt future".

Comment: Ah; I now remember him jumping out of the "silhouette podium" to attack Silik.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler : Indeed, but it was never made clear that the future humanoid who we had been seeing was Archer --- only that Daniels had returned Archer to that exact place (the podium) and time so that he could stop Silik.  There was also a long-running rumour about a Romulan being the Future Guy.  Braga's tweets settled the issue once and for all.

Comment: Yeah, true. I was thinking he was a Vulcan at first, then considered that he may be a Romulan once they started to appear in the series. Thanks! I didn't expect there to be such a clear-cut answer.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler : No worries!  You're welcome.  :-)

Comment: There are much longer and better explanations of this. There were PLANS for him to be Archer, but that was decided not to be the case, or up for debate throughout production and it was never settled on so it is wrong to say it was archer, because it was never shown to be the case and from how its described production seems to have been going against this idea the further along in the series they were getting.

Comment: @Durakken : I'm quoting executive producer Brannon Braga directly. According to him  it was settled.  If you take issue with this, you should bring it up with him on Twitter.

Comment: Sorry, no. Tweets several years later that contradict previous statements are less accurate and valid a source than interviews that are closer to the production and are more in line with what other sources say. He probably is just remembering wrong or making stuff up as it is a long ago for him now and he's worked on other things. Even if it were the case that was 100% absolutely the plan, at any CBS or any number of events could have and can nix the idea from ever becoming canon so it's wrong to say it is.

Comment: @Durakken : I'm not doubting you, but he made these statements on two separate occasions, three years apart.

Comment: several years after he made contradictory comments and contradicting everything said previous to that during production. Once he started remembering differently during the 2012 tweets it's not surprising he would keep misremembering after that point, however the further removed he is from production the more likely he is to misremember.

Comment: Actually Future Guy might have been a Romulan. It was just a time travelling scientist that replaced the Romulan Guy for a few days using the Quantum Leap technology. Others would still see him as the Romulan Guy.

Comment: He was trying to prevent the Kelvin timeline.

Comment: @JerryNixon it's the only way to save Porthos!