# Which pre-Federation wars did this character refer to, and did he describe them accurately?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Near the end of Star Trek Beyond, pre-Federation wars between Earth and nonhumans are discussed - Krall laments to Kirk that "millions were lost" fighting the Romulans and either the Xindi or the Kzinti. (I'm not sure which of those names he actually said - I initially thought I heard Kzinti, but that seemed like a startlingly obscure reference.)

Which of these wars were referred to, and is Krall correct in claiming they cost millions of human lives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The Xindi and Romulan wars — he is correct about their toll

Krall is referring to two bloody campaigns in Earth's pre-Federation history.

**Xindi campaign**

At the start of the third season of *Enterprise*, the Xindi, a group of five different species from a single planet in the unexplored Delphic Expanse, had used a prototype weapon to attack Earth.  The attack, which occurred in March 2153, killed **seven million people**, including a close relative of the Enterprise's chief engineer, Trip Tucker.

This led Starfleet to send Captain Archer's Enterprise with a team of MACOs (Military Assault Command Operations officers) into the Expanse to locate the Xindi, where they spent almost a year.  The Enterprise lost nearly 30 crew members / MACOs during the mission.

Krall himself was

> a MACO during this time, as revealed in *Beyond*.  (This leads to a [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135171/was-this-character-from-star-trek-beyond-on-archers-ship).)

It was not a full-on "war", but given the casualties suffered in the initial attack, it was certainly a bloody conflict.

You can read more about the Xindi campaign [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Xindi_incident).

**Earth-Romulan War**

The fourth season of *Enterprise* sets the stage for the Earth-Romulan War, a lengthy conflict beginning in 2156 that ending in stalemate in 2160.  Its long-term effect was the establishment of the Federation-Romulan Neutral Zone, an interstellar no-go zone for either party that was first mentioned in the *Original Series* episode "Balance of Terror" and whose existence persisted into the *TNG* era.

The exact death toll of the war has never been reported in the Star Trek canon, but given that it was four years long, it is generally assumed to have been a costly war, with deep residual resentment on both sides.  For instance, as Spock reveals in "Balance of Terror":

> **SPOCK:** Earth believes the Romulans to be warlike, cruel, treacherous, and only the Romulans know what they think of Earth. The treaty, set by sub-space radio, established this Neutral Zone, entry into which by either side, would constitute an act of war.

You can read more about the Earth-Romulan war [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-Romulan_War).

Comment: dam shame we didnt get a 5th season war

Comment: @Himarm : Season 5 would have also revealed [Future Guy to be Archer and why](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131475/who-was-informing-the-suliban-cabal-in-the-temporal-cold-war/131483)!

Comment: You're going to have to substantiate the claim that he participated in the Xindi War, cuz it literally didn't happen for anyone other than Archer's crew and even that is iffy... and then that was 100 years prior and he must have been at least 25 then. Even pushing it under normal life spans and such he'd be 120ish. Given these facts, without substantiation either the writers flubbed this, or it simply isn't true. (Memory Alpha needs to do this too as it likewise doesn't have a citation) He could have fought agains the Kzinti and Romulans though.

Comment: @Durakken : Did you see *Beyond*?  A major point (I hate to throw in a spoiler, but I feel I need to) is that Krall was a MACO from before the time of the Federation and that he used alien technology to extend his life unnaturally.   He was considered a hero for his actions in the Xindi and Romulan wars and was given a captaincy as a reward.  He crash-landed on the planet in *Beyond*, where he found the life extension technology and went crazy (not necessarily in that order).

Comment: @Durakken : All of this is mentioned in *Beyond*.

Comment: Is it specifically mentioned that he fought the Xindi on Archer's ship, cuz I don't see any citation that says this.

Comment: @Durakken : Well, I'm not sure about *direct* participation.  That's why I asked [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135171/was-this-character-from-star-trek-beyond-on-archers-ship) myself.  He may have been stationed on Earth near the Xindi attack site in Florida or may have been part of an orbital defense team....

Comment: If that's the case then he couldn't have participated because once Archer won this whole thing everything reverted to a timeline where it didn't happen. Only possibly Archer's crew due to some temporal shielding or some such remember any different... I'd say unless it is specifically stated it is better to assume they are referring to a Kzinti War, not the Xindi War.

Comment: @Durakken : Well, I would say we don't have clear evidence that we are in the reverted timeline.

Comment: @Durakken : Also, this article based on an interview with *Beyond* writers Pegg and Jung indicates the Xindi.  https://www.buzzfeed.com/adambvary/star-trek-beyond-simon-pegg-doug-jung?utm_term=.kfQaopA5l#.gtYakr0Xe

Comment: I'm not saying it's not "possibly the case." I'm saying it's more likely in-universe that he isn't. It certainly is likely the only way it makes sense, but it's one of those things that shouldn't be taken as fact (because there is always bad writing in these things) until it is said directly in the canon, even if the creators say it directly I'd still say not to take it as 100% fact, because things change and get added, especially with franchises like Star Trek.

Comment: @Durakken : Sure, I'm just going on what we know at the moment.  I will edit / update this as new information arises.

Comment: I listened several times and I think he said Xindi War. I just got done watching the movie. The problem is that he is growling and such while saying it.

Comment: @Durakken Given that you've reviewed the line, did he say that *he* fought in those wars? As I recall, he was describing wars fought by humanity as a whole.

Comment: @recognizer Yes he said "I fought through..."

Comment: @Durakken Also, yeah, I think that's a consequence of Elba's concept that Krall "had to redesign his brain to speak English again" after a long time without using the language - http://www.reuters.com/article/us-film-startrek-idris-elba-idUSKCN10003L - his performance is interesting for sure but makes no concessions for comprehensibility :)