# What was future Archer going to gain by stopping Mankind?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

That silhouetted guy who used to command Silik [was actually Archer from future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131483/931).

If you can remember what he made Silik do, he also tried to stop Mankind from its deep space missions (once Enterprise shuttle by mistake destroyed a female-dominant race which triggered Vulcan rage; real culprits were Sulibans). At that time, temporal agents from 31st century helped mankind prove that they weren't guilty. At that time, I thought other factions of Temporal Cold War were behind this (possibly it was even mentioned in the show).

But, if that silhouetted guy was Archer from future, what was he going to gain from ruining mankind? It doesn't matter how much corrupt he became in the future, those things were going to limit himself (creating even paradox of him no longer able to project himself into past).

Comment: been a while, but i dont think it was always archer. just the one time when he jumped out to attack the main suliban guy. just because someone said in a tweet that it was archer does not mean its official; it never was revealed. but if you believe the tweets then from that link you see that he did it because he was trying to correct some future wrong. your answer is right there. we dont know what the motives may have been officially, because the series was cancelled before it could be revealed. but if the future was changed there would be no need to time travel; so the paradox is moot.

Comment: @Odin1806: “just because someone said in a tweet that it was archer does not mean its official” — true, although when that someone is [Brannon Braga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise#Crew), that gives it a bit more weight.

Comment: Whether or not a paradox is created in Star Trek seems to depend on what technology and what actions are involved in the time travel.  There's been plenty of times when something like this is successful (in particular, [O'Brien's jumps in DS9](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Visionary_(episode)) come to mind).